# Reload node with new URL in JStree

Tags: url, refresh, jstree

I am developing an application with 2 ajax elements. On the left side of the page I am using JsTree for navigation and on the right hand side I am displaying search form with datatable content relevant to the Tree element that is clicked. When user searches/filters on the right hand side page the relevant node in the tree should reload to show the filtered content.
This is something similar to Windows File Explorer or Eclipse Explorer (with synchronization).

On Click of search button in Search form the currently selected node in tree should reload:
I am able to set the new url in jsTree using set settings. (alert shows new url).
However when node is refreshed its refreshed using the url specified during jsTree init.
Please help me reload the node with new url. (Note: I cannot use bind events with tree as action performed is on a button outside the tree.)

```
$('#searchbtn').live('click', function() {
var tree = jQuery.jstree._reference("#tree_container");
var currentNode = tree._get_node($(".jstree-clicked"), false);
settings = jQuery("#tree_container").jstree('get_settings');
settings.json_data.ajax.url = "<%= request.getContextPath() %>"/inventory/tree/getTree?search=abcd
jQuery("#tree_container").jstree('set_settings', settings); 
alert("new settings url: "+settings.json_data.ajax.url);
tree.refresh(currentNode);
});

$(function () {
    var tree = $("#tree_container")
        .jstree({ 
        "json_data" : {
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/inventory/tree/getTree",
        "data": function (n) {
          return {
            "operation": "get_children",
            "id": n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node_", "") : 0,
            "elementType": n.attr ? n.attr("elementType") : "notdefined",
            "page": n.attr ? n.attr("page") : "nopage"
          };
    }
  }
},
"types": {
  "types": {
    "max_children": -2,
    "max_depth": -2
  }
},
"ui": {
  "initially_select": ["node_1"]
},
"core": {
  // just open those two nodes up   
  // as this is an AJAX enabled tree, both will be downloaded from the server
  "initially_open": ["node_1"]
},
"themes": {
  "theme": "classic",
  "dots" : true,
        "url" : "assets/css/tree/classic/style.css"
},
"plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "types", "hotkeys"]
```

})

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#treeElement').bind("select_node.jstree", function(e,data) {
    var obj = $("#treeElement").jstree("get_selected");
    var tree = jQuery.jstree._reference("#treeElement");
    tree.refresh(obj);
});
```